# Filtering lines from file

Tags: perl

I would like to capture lines from a file that contain:  "ExprControl" or "5p3pAssays" or "Fusion".

However, I would like to skip lines that contain both “Fusion” and “NoCall”. How do I correctly omit these lines? The code below fails to skip lines that contain both "Fusion" and "NoCall". Thank you.

```
...
       open my $in_fh, '<', $full_tsv_file
       or die qq{Unable to open "$full_tsv_file" for input: $!};

         while ( <$in_fh> ) {

            next if /^#/;
            next if /\b(?:Fusion&NoCall)\b/;
     next unless /\b(?:ExprControl|5p3pAssays|Fusion)\b/;


            my @fields = split('\t');

            my $location = $fields[$location_col]; $location =~ s/"//g;
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&` doesn't mean "and" in regular expressions. Match twice with `&&` instead:

```
while (<>) {
    next if /^#/ || /\bFusion\b/ && /\bNoCall\b/;
    next unless /\b(?:Fusion|5p3pAssays|ExprControl)\b/;
    print;
}
```

Tested against:

```
a ExprControl b
c 5p3pAssays d
e Fusion f NoCall g
h NoCall i Fusion j
k Fusion l
```